# How do I use Generics in a function call using Measurements in Swift 3

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I need a function that works with the value in any Measurement in Swift 3. Below is an example:

```
var test2 = Measurement<UnitEnergy>( value: 10.1234, unit: .calories)

func printMeasurementGeneric( measurement: Measurement<Unit>) {
    print( measurement.value)
}

func printMeasurementEnergy( measurement: Measurement<UnitEnergy>) {
    print( measurement.value)
}

printMeasurementEnergy(measurement: test2) // This works
printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: test2)  // This doesn't work and give the following error

Playground execution failed: error: Measurement Playground.playground:136:38: error: cannot convert value of type 'Measurement<UnitEnergy>' to expected argument type 'Measurement<Unit>'
printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: test2)
```

What does the function need to look like for PrintMeasurementGeneric for this to work?

I've made some progress and now have the following code in Swift playground

```
var test = Measurement<UnitEnergy>( value: 10.1234, unit: .calories)

func printMeasurementGeneric<A:Dimension>( measurement: Measurement<A>) {
    print( measurement.value)
}

// This works
printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: test) // This works

// The following doesn't work
var objectValue: Any?
objectValue = test

var meas = objectValue as! Measurement<Dimension> // Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.Measurement<NSUnitEnergy>' (0x11d324028) to 'Foundation.Measurement<NSDimension>' (0x11d324088).
printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: meas)
```

I'm trying to use the objectValue in an NSControl to hold the Measurement. How do I do this within checking if it can be cast to every measurement type?

Some more work and including edits from below. Not a pretty or robust solution.

```
var test = Measurement<UnitEnergy>( value: 10.1234, unit: .calories)

func printMeasurementGeneric<A>( measurement: Measurement<A>) {
    print( measurement.value)
}

// This works
printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: test) // This works

// The following works but isn't pretty. Is there a better way
var objectValue: Any?
objectValue = test

if objectValue is Measurement<UnitFrequency> {
    let meas = objectValue as! Measurement<UnitFrequency>
    printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: meas)
} else if objectValue is Measurement<UnitLength> {
    let meas = objectValue as! Measurement<UnitLength>
    printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: meas)
} else if objectValue is Measurement<UnitSpeed> {
    let meas = objectValue as! Measurement<UnitSpeed>
    printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: meas)
}  else if objectValue is Measurement<UnitEnergy> {
    let meas = objectValue as! Measurement<UnitEnergy>
    printMeasurementGeneric(measurement: meas)
} else {
    print("Didn't find cast!")
}
```

Comment: Step one is to stop this practice of beginning a function name with a capital letter. Just stop it. Now. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the capitalization. Step 2 in getting the measurement out of objectValue is an NSControl?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `PrintMeasurementGeneric` function to this.

```
func PrintMeasurementGeneric<Dimension>( measurement: Measurement<Dimension>) {
  print( measurement.value)
}
```

I used the `Dimension` type instead of `Unit`. Either should work but all of the measurement types conform to `Dimension` (an abstract subclass of `Unit`).

Hamish (below) is right.

Comment: I think there's a little bit of confusion here – saying `<Dimension>` introduces a new generic placeholder called `Dimension`, but is completely unrelated to `Foundation`'s `Dimension` class – you could go ahead and call the generic placeholder `FooBar` and it wouldn't make a difference. Also you're incorrect in saying that "*`Dimension` and `Unit` are protocols*" – they are actually classes. The reason the cast doesn't work is that generics are invariant.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a protocol:

```
protocol HasValue {
    var value: Double { get set }
}
extension Measurement: HasValue { }

func printValue<T: HasValue>(of item: T) {
    print(item.value) // prints "10.1234"
}


var test = Measurement<UnitEnergy>( value: 10.1234, unit: .calories)
printValue(of: test)
```

Any function similar to printValue should be able to use any measurement generically. You could include the functions in a protocol extension for organization.